# Control mplayer ran by xargs

Tags: mplayer, xargs

I feed mplayer with file list from another command:

```
beet ls somequery -p | xargs -d '\n' mplayer
```

When invoked this way, mplayer doesn't react on any standard keys, all I can do is to C-c interrupt it.

1. Why does this happen?
2. How to make mplayer behave (without writing any bigger code, no loops, regexp or multiple pipes)?

Answer (score 1):

James's idea can be implemented without an extra file descriptor:

```
beet ls QUERY | xargs -d '\n' sh -c 'mplayer "$@" < /dev/tty'
```

The same approach is suggested in `xargs` manual page (the last example, spawning copies of `emacs`).

Comment: It seems that BSD version of xargs has an -o (--open-tty) option exactly for that.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/30367/how-can-i-retain-the-console-input-in-mplayer-when-reading-from-stdin#30434) which passes args from `find`, I came up with the following script:

```
$ beet ls QUERY | mplayer -playlist /dev/fd/3 3<&0 </dev/tty
```

Quick explanation as how I understand it: `mplayer` is told to read `/dev/fd/3` as a playlist file. File descriptor 3 (`/dev/fd/3`) is filled by the standard input (`3<&0`) from the `beet` command. And input to `mplayer` is specified as the controlling terminal (`</dev/tty`). Because mplayer is reading from a file and not stdin, you can control it with the keyboard.

This works for me under Mac OS 10.8.3.